# Declaration-site variance may cause ClassCastException

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin introduces Declaration-site variance described at [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance).

The out/in keywords for generic parameters may cause ClassCastException in some case. My program is shown below.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var l: List<String> = mutableListOf("string")
    demo(l)
    println("======")
    for (s in l) {
        println(s)
    }
}

fun demo(strs: List<String>) {
    val objects: List<Any> = strs // This is OK, since T is an out-parameter
    if (objects is MutableList) {
        val obs: MutableList<Any> = objects as MutableList<Any>
        obs.add(TextView())
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.kotlin.demo.clzz.TextView cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.kotlin.demo.clzz.Declaration_Site_VarianceKt.main(Declaration-Site-Variance.kt:14)
======
adn
```

Is the way to use out/in keywords a recommended practice? and Why?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It appears that you are subverting a list of strings by trying to add a non-string, and Kotlin, rightly, is complaining about it. Lists of String can only hold Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be compiled without any warnings, this is because [declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) only available in Kotlin.

> This is in contrast with Java's use-site variance where wildcards in the type usages make the types covariant.

For example 2 `Soruce` interfaces use [declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) in Kotlin:

```
interface Source<out T> 
interface Source<in T>
```

Both of the two `Source` interfaces will be generated into the same source code in Java as below:

```
//                      v---`T extends Object` rather than `? extends T` 
public interface Source<T>{ /**/ }
```

This is because wildcard `?` is used as a type argument rather than a type parameter in Java.
The `T` in `Source<T>` is a **type parameter** and the `? extends String` in `Source<? extends String>` is a **type argument**.

So if you use [type projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections) to make the `objects` force to a `List<out Any>`, then the compiler will reports an *UNCHECKED_CAST* warning  , for example:

```
fun demo(strs: List<String>) {
    //                v--- makes it explicitly by using out type proejction
    val objects: List<out Any> = strs 
    if (objects is MutableList) {
         //                                 v--- an UNCHECKED_CAST warning reported
        val obs: MutableList<Any> = objects as MutableList<Any>
        obs.add(TextView())
    }
}
```

In other words, you can't assign a `List<out Any>` to a `MutableList<Any>`. Otherwise, you will get a compilation error. for example:

```
fun demo(strs: List<String>) {
    val objects: List<out Any> = strs 
    if (objects is MutableList) {
        //                                v--- ? extends Object
        //ERROR: can't assign MutableList<out Any> to Mutable<Any> 
        //                          v                          ^--- Object
        val obs: MutableList<Any> = objects
        obs.add(TextView())
    }
}
```

**IF** you assign the `objects` to a `MutableList<out Any>` variable, you'll found that you can't adding anything, since you can't create `Nothing` in Kotlin at all. for example:

```
fun demo(strs: List<String>) {
    val objects: List<out Any> = strs
    if (objects is MutableList) {
        //                   v--- down-casting to `MutableList<out Any>` 
        val obs: MutableList<out Any> = objects
        //      v---ERROR: can't be instantiated
        obs.add(Nothing())
    }
}
```

> **Q**: Is the way to use out/in keywords a recommended practice?

Java has described [how to use a wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) and it also applies in Kotlin.

An "**in**" Variable, note "**in**" in here is `? extends T` and it is same with Kotlin **out** variance:

> An "in" variable serves up data to the code. Imagine a copy method with two arguments: `copy(src, dest)`. The ***src*** argument provides the data to be copied, so it is the "**in**" parameter.

An "**out**" Variable, note "**out**" in here is `? super T` and it is  same with Kotlin **in** variance:

> An "**out**" variable holds data for use elsewhere. In the copy example, `copy(src, dest)`, the ***dest*** argument accepts data, so it is the "**out**" parameter.